# Convergence order of Runge-Kutta methods: proof requested

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have been told that:

> The convergence order of an explicit Runge-Kutta method with $s$ stages is at most $s$. Furthermore, for $s>5$ there is no explicit Runge-Kutta $s$-stage method of order $s$.

How do I prove that? And what about implicit and semi-implicit ones?

Comment: Generally, people find Taylor expansions of both the function being approximated and the Runge-Kutta approximation, then compare the two.  If the coefficients of the difference of their Taylor series is $a_k h^k + a_{k+1} h^{k+1} + ... $ with $a_k \neq 0$, then the method is of order $k-1$.  I assume that upon expanding an $s$-stage method for $s > 5$, one finds that the algebraic conditions to achieve order $s$ are insoluble.

Answer (score 1):

This is well known as the Butcher Barrier.

For textbooks, you find a proof in [Norsett, Hairer, Wanner ODE 1](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-78862-1), Chapter ||.5

The original paper by Butcher is [this](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/on-rungekutta-processes-of-high-order/40DFE501CAB781C9AAE1439B6B8F481A), while there are around that time similar works, see for instance [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1966-20-093/S0025-5718-1966-0187406-1/).

For implicit methods, in principle arbitrary high order can be realized, e.g. by [Gauss-Legendre methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_method).

I am not entirely sure what you mean by semi-implicit - are you referring to diagonally implicit methods?